# removing exclamation mark from a string javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I know this code works but I dont understand it, could someone please explain.

```
function remove(s){
return s.replace(/!+$/, '');
}
remove('Hi!'); // outputs 'Hi'
remove('!Hi'); // outputs 'Hi'
```

I understand the ! is replaced with the empty string but what are the back slashes, plus and dollar signs???
thanks

Comment: *"`remove('!Hi');` // outputs 'Hi'"* - No, it outputs `'!Hi'`. The function removes any exclamation marks that are at the *end* of the string, ignoring others. The *forward* slashes in `/!+$/` are JS syntax for a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) literal. The `+` means to match the previous thing one or more times. The `$` matches the end of the string.

Comment: `what are the back slashes` - there are NO back slashes \ ...

Comment: These are things that you'd learn when reading a beginner's language tutorial. http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no backslashes, those are forward slashes. They're the syntax for Javascript RegExp literals, just as quotes are used around strings.

`+` and `$` are part of regular expression syntax. `+` means to match 1 or more of the preceding pattern (`!` in this case) and `$` matches the end of the string. So this will replace a sequence of `!` at the end of the string.

You should read a tutorial on regular expressions. Go to [regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expression.info).

Since it only matches `!` at the end of the string, `remove('!Hi')` should return `!Hi`, not `Hi`.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input and links. I will read though and hopefully have a good understanding after.